# Openpyxl TypeError: Table.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'displayName'

Tags: python, openpyxl, reportlab

I got this error with openpyxl

```
TypeError: Table.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'displayName'
```

I've checked everything with the documentation and it looks eaxctly the same like in my code.
[Openpyxl docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worksheet_tables.html)

I've tried to remove displayName then the the error changed to ref keyword.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo

from reportlab import Table


#........ data is a list like in the example

   # Create a Workbook instance
    wb = Workbook()
    # Create sheets
    ws_source = wb.active

    # Append data to the first sheet
    for row_data in data:
        ws_source.append(row_data)
    
    ws_source.title = "Source Sample List"
    # Create a table with the data
    table_range = "A1:I" + str(len(data))
    tab = Table(displayName="SourceSampleTable", ref=table_range)
    tab.tableStyleInfo = TableStyleInfo(
        name="TableStyleMedium9", showFirstColumn=False, showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=True
    )
    ws_source.add_table(tab)  # Add the table to the sheet
```

Comment: Check the `Table` class is really what you think it is.

Comment: I agree with Charlie. At the top you are importing the `Table` class correctly, but maybe you overwrite `Table` afterwards accidentally, or maybe the version of openpyxl you have has a different class. Before the line `tab = Table(displayName="SourceSampleTable", ref=table_range)`, add a line `print(dir(Table))`. You should see `displayName` as one of the properties of the class (if you don't then `Table` is not the one you thought).

Comment: I'm using the newest version of openpyxl and I'm not overwriting it. It stuck on that line:
tab = Table(displayName="SourceSampleTable", ref=table_range)
it can't create Table. My import from openpyxl is exact same like in the documentation from openpyxl

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code, with the line "from reportlab import Table" you replace the openpyxl Table. You need to change your import style to prevent such namespace issues, eg. "import reportlab", then call that table object as "reportlab.Table".

Answer (score 0):

Already solved it few days ago, but was deleted:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table as ExcelTable, TableStyleInfo
```